# How to export large tables from SQL Server to csv quickly?

Tags: python, sql, r, sql-server

I am trying to export large (10 million rows) table to a semicolon separated `.csv` file. I am currently using build in tool (Import/Export Wizard) in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17 and the export takes approximately 5 hours.

Is there a simple way to speed up this process?

I am limited by my company to use only R/python solution, beside of course SQL Server itself.

Comment: The best mechanism (in R or python) in my experience is to use `sqlcmd`, a command-line tool. The overhead associated with forking a process, downloading the data into a mostly-CSV file, and then reading it in is typically lower than a "normal" call to `DBI::dbGetQuery`. (I'm assuming that your query is optimized (e.g., indexes are properly set and being used well) and that network bandwidth is not the limiting factor.)

Comment: That sounds extraordinarily slow. Are there very very many columns? How large is the current output file?    I tried the example at the following link with 10M rows and most methods took around a second to write a ~300MB CSV: https://www.danielecook.com/speeding-up-reading-and-writing-in-r/

Comment: How blinkered/fuzzy is your company's definition of SQL Server? The fastest method you're likely to find is the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility). `bcp.exe` is part of every SQL Server installation, it's just not directly accessible inside T-SQL. For regular exports, though, it's commonly scheduled in SQL Agent jobs and can consume the output of stored procedures and user-defined table-valued functions, not just entire tables and views.

Comment: Table is quite wide (600 columns), output file has around 25 Gb.

Comment: @Miczab why are you doing this *at all*? What are you trying to accomplish? There are probably better ways to do ti. `and the export takes approximately 5 hours.` what makes you think any other tool will be faster?  How fast is your disk? Do other processes use it? If you try to export the data in the same disk as the database, you just halved the IO bandwidth. If the table is in use, your reads will be blocked by any modifications

Comment: @Miczab Import/Export Wizard is a wizard over Integration Services which is far faster than any Python or R solution - instead of loading all data in memory and writing it, Integration Services uses a pipeline of processing steps, reading the data in a stream, processing individual rows and writing them out to the target. This way you can handle far more data than any RAM-based solution would allow, and start producing output as soon as the first batch of rows was processed

Comment: @Miczab finally, what does your query do? An inefficient query can't be accelerated by any client-side technique.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am forced to export this table to csv, because it is an input file to commercial tool, which dose not except any other format. The file has around 20 mln rows and 600 columns, around 32 Gb. I am not power user in my organization so I have limited option of tools.

Comment: Doesn't that commercial tool work with direct database connections, eg using ODBC? It would be **very** strange for any commercial tool to fail at this. In any case, 5 hours is way too much, and 10M rows not that much. What does your query look like? Are you exporting the file to the same disk as the database? Right now you haven't provided any useful information except the data size.

Comment: Are you exporting to the same machine or a different machine over the network? No Python solution will be faster than direct writes, or improve the performance of your disks and network card

Comment: I am exporting to different machine over network. Commercial tool unfortunately dose not support ODBC - only flat files, nothing can be done in this regard. I am using the SSMS Export Import Wizard, exporting from Sql Server 11 to flat file, without writing any query per se.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data source connection.

I use OLEDB and am able to export to CSV ~2GB in ~2mins.

What is the size (in memory) of your table?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31001516)

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Above comments aside - this is a useful point, enquiries down this path may well help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Python or any code base involved, accomplishing this by query is almost always the best solution. I'm assuming the table has a primary key. (even if it's only a rowid)

Make sure the primary key is used to extract the data. Using code, you can organize your queries in loops and grab the data by the primary key. You can use Python(in this case) to build local support tables to help loop and pull the data in batches. This will allow you extract the data (and be able to use it) in the fastest way possible. I had this same issue and even investigated multiple paths including bcp utility and stored procedures. I would definitely stick with Python in this case. You're adding overhead by extracting data to files and then accessing those files. You could be managing the data real time. 10 million rows is not a big number.